# Create an array based on a Jquery Mobile List

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, soundmanager2

I have a list within jQuery Mobile. The list will have an id number and a search query number such as this

```
"<li><a href='./page.html?id=2' data-transition='slide' id=1>Name</a></li>";
```

and

```
"<li><a href='./page.html?id=10' data-transition='slide' id=2>Name</a></li>";
```

I create this list from an ajax call back so it is printed on the page like this `$('#list').html(data);`.

What I would like to do is have the list within an array so that when a user clicks one of the list options it would pull the information based on the search query or `?id=2` but the user could click a button on move to the next list item which is `id=2`.

So the search query gets the correct info from the database but the id is the position within the array.

Below is the code to populate the list its a callback from an ajax function

```
function trackscallback(rtndata) 
{ 

var data="";
for(j=0;j<=rtndata.length -1;j++)
{
    data = data + "<li><a href='./page.html?id="+rtndata[j].track_id+"' data-transition='slide' id="+rtndata[j].name+"><h3>" + rtndata[j].name + "</h3><p><strong>" + rtndata[j].a_name + "</strong></p><p>" + rtndata[j].genre+ "</p></a></li>";
}
$('#list').html(data);
$('#list').listview('refresh'); 
}
```

So this code will create a list in my DOM the user can click on of these to get more information or in my case play an mp3. The issue I have is that this can only enable a user to play one mp3 at a time. This means when the mp3 is finished playing the user has to go back to the list to select a new mp3 to play.

What I want is I want is that after the user selects an item from the list after it has completed playing it goes to the next item on the list and plays that.

My code for playing the mp3s is as follows:

```
function playtrackcallback(rtndata) 
{ 
track = rtndata.artist_name + " " + "-" + " " + rtndata.track_name;
picture = "<img src='"+rtndata.track_art_url+"'/>";
playingSongId = rtndata.track_id;
$('#songPicture').html(picture);
$('#songName').text(track);
playSong(rtndata);
}

function playSong(rtndata) {
        //Stop the sound from playing
        soundManager.destroySound(mySound);

        //Save some variables
        playingSong = rtndata.track_id;

        //Create the sound and begin playing whenever!
        soundManager.createSound({
            id: mySound,
            url: rtndata.track_url,
            autoPlay: true,
            stream: true,
            onplay: function () {
                setPauseState(false);
                setPlayTime();
            },
```

Comment: The array is _data_, or is there another array?

Comment: if all you need is ID to send to server why not just add another data attribute with that ID, or sychronize element `id` so it matches query id. Then when clcik link grab ID from attribute and send to server. Not 100% clear what you need to do with this `array`, what i needs to contain or how you plan to access it

Comment: the query id matches back to my database primary key. So that means it wont be the same position within the array so they need to be separate numbers. I need an array because I want the user to be able to move from one list item to the other list item without having to go back to the list and select the next item in the list

Comment: As I understand it, you don't need an array. Everything known client-side about the list is *in* the list and can therefore be retrieved dynamically *from* the list - ie from the DOM - unless there's some aspect you haven't described.

Comment: Btw, `id="1"` `id="2"` starting with numbers cant be used in jQuery, if you want to call them by `id`.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot ok so am guessing the `#list` already has the info so how then can I move onto the next list item using jQuery as it is already in the DOM

Comment: @Omar thanks will make the change seeing that it may be possible to pull the information from the DOM instead

Comment: Can you post a code and explain more about what you want to achieve?

Comment: Will post some more code hope it helps

Comment: Code posted with a bit more clarification

Comment: Ok, will go through it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27254/discussion-between-omar-and-kern-elliott)

Comment: Check this, continuous playlist. I'll update my answer if this solution suits you. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Vcm9U/

Comment: your last jsfiddle above this has hit the nail on the head this is exactly what I am looking for. The only comment I would say is that you do not need to remove the values from the array when going to the next it can just end at the last array spot or start over from the top of the list.

Comment: Also remember I update the content on the page based on the href query string so with that I would update the header within the page. Omar thanks alot for all the help you continue to give me thus far

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example, I hope it works for you.

Comment: When I click next nothing happens is there anyway I can show you the entire project together

Comment: when I click on the button I get an alert but the href and id on not change

Comment: this works fine thanks for the solution now I need to find a way to stop having to go back tru all the songs when going back

Comment: @KernElliott Pls check the updated demo. I have added more features. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I don't know if all that code is neccessary as i know the url of the index page most of the time their is only one time I will do a query string before I reach the player. Is it possible to store the url before I call the `href="#player"` and in doing this store it in the href of the "back button"?

Comment: the lastpage code is getting errors for some reason

Comment: @Omar added some information in the chat area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Upated answer**

To create an Array of all links following the click list item.

**[Demo page](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/kX4su/)**

**Markup** / *the naughty button!*

```
<a class="next" data-role="button" href="" id="" data-inline="true">Next</a>
```

**Code**

```
// Create Array
var links = [];

$('li').on('click', 'a', function (e) {

 // Find all links after the clicked link/list item
 var list = $(this).closest('li').nextAll('li').find('a');

 // Wipe array
 links = [];

 // Push href and id of each link
 if (list.length > 0) {
    $.each(list, function () {
        links.push({
            'href': $(this).attr('href'),
                'id': $(this).attr('id')
        });
    });
 }
});

// Next song button
$('a.next').on('click', function (e) {

 // Update (Next) button href and id
 if (links.length > 0) {
  var nexthref = links[0].href;
  var nextid = links[0].id;
  $('a.next').attr('href', nexthref);
  $('a.next').attr('id', nextid);

  // Remove used values from Array
  links.splice(0, 1);
}
 // Move to next song
 $.mobile.changePage($(this).attr('href'), {
    transition: 'flip'
 });
});
```

**Controls** - Show/Hide 'Next' and 'Back' buttons (*based on my demo*)

```
// Last page
var lastpage = '#' + $('body').find('div[data-role="page"]').last()[0].id;

// Hide 'Next' button / Add button 'Back' button
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', lastpage, function () {
 $('a.next').hide();
 $('[data-role=content]').append('<a class="last" data-role="button" href="#songs" data-inline="true">Back to Index</a>').trigger('create');
});

// Remove 'Back' button / show 'Next' button
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#songs', function () {
 $('a.next').show();
 $('a.last').remove();
});
```

Comment: this work fantastically however when a user selects a link lets say link 3 which has an id of id3 within your example how will it then move to id4 by pressing a button

Comment: To go to next mp3 automatically? I'm working on it. @KernElliott

Comment: Ok thanks alot if you need any more information please feel free to ask

Comment: @KernElliott pls check my updated answer and let me know what you think :)

Comment: I can see both the href and the id in the array am still not sure how I can click the button with the id `nextSong` to move through the array to get the values though

Comment: @KernElliott so you need to assign a button for next song only, or following songs?

Comment: Consider it to be a music player when you press next it goes to the next song on the list regardless if the list is 3 songs or a 100. So I would say it is for the following songs

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27288/discussion-between-omar-and-kern-elliott)